# How would I access this JSON file using React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json, react-native

I have a functioning react native app that uses a tab bar. On my current version, I can make it display a flat list from VSON that I found from a youtube video. I want to use my own JSON list now, but I'm having issues.

Here's a link to the online JSON file: api.jsonbin.io/b/5b3a49c8a5a2f34ea6b0fbc8

Here's my code for the specific file I'm working on that I got from the youtube video (this works and displays a list of names). Please note this is a tab in my tab bar:

My question is what do I need to set 
    this.setState({ data: json.results })
 to, and then what do I set 
     
          {`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
        }

if I just wanted to display medicationCodeableConcept

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
FlatList
} from "react-native";

import { Icon } from 'native-base'


class LikesTab extends Component {

//SETTING THE STATE MAKING AN EMPTY ARRAY WHICH WE FIL
  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
this.fetchData();
  }

//Getting the data
  fetchData = async () => {
const response = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api?results=500");
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: json.results });
  };

  //var customData = require('./customData.json');


//Setting what is shown
  render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Text>
          {`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
        </Text>}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}
export default LikesTab;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
});
```

Here's my current code that just shows  a blank screen:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
FlatList
} from "react-native";

import { Icon } from 'native-base'


class LikesTab extends Component {

//SETTING THE STATE MAKING AN EMPTY ARRAY WHICH WE FIL
  state = {
data: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
this.fetchData();
  }

//Getting the data
  fetchData = async () => {
const response = await fetch("api.jsonbin.io/b/5b3a49c8a5a2f34ea6b0fbc8");
const json = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: json.results });
  };

  //var customData = require('./customData.json');


//Setting what is shown
  render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        <Text>
          {`${item.entry.medicationCodeableConcept}`}
        </Text>}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}
export default LikesTab;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are setting the state,you are setting an undefined value of `json.results`
Instead of that you need to do this

```
fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'http://api.jsonbin.io/b/5b3a49c8a5a2f34ea6b0fbc8'
    );

    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    this.setState({ data: json.entry });
  };
```

And when rendering use

```
        <Text>{item.resource.medicationCodeableConcept.text}</Text>
```